# Postgresql: most common values in array column

Tags: postgresql, query

I have a table which looks like this:

```
post_id   tags
---       ----
1         {'tag1','tag2','tag3'}
2         {'foo','tag3', 'tag1'}
3         {'bar','tag3','anothertag'}
...
```

**Tags is an *array* column.**

**Is there any way to get the most common tags (e.g. to generate a *tag cloud*)?**

For example, how do you get the tag names sorted by popularity or the top 10 tags used? (in the above example, in order: `tag3`, `tag1`, etc.)

Is it possible to compute that efficiently (for thousands of rows)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unnest the array, then aggregate and group:

```
select u.tag, count(*)
from the_table t
  cross join unnest(t.tags) as u(tag)
group by u.tag
order by count(*) desc
limit 10;
```